# starting .net development in ironpython

Tags: .net, ironpython

I'm in a situation where i need to start learning some .net to work with some application at work.

Currently my knowledge is mainly in python and php so i'm interested in taking the iron python route to learning and implementing .net .

Is this a good idea by any stretch and/or is there any good resources to get started learning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in luck... [IronPython In Action](http://www.manning.com/foord/) was just released within the past week or two.